# How to have title centered with multiple centered lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

Right now I try this:

```
\title{I am an interesting \newline headline \newline that \newline sticks out}
\maketitle
\newpage
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

Instead, it should look like this (where everything is centered relative to the page):

```
      I am an interesting
           headline
             that
          sticks out
```

Comment: Replace the `\newline`s by `\endgraf`.

Comment: `\newline` is a command that does not do what most people expect it to do. Best to forget about it. For the title field, you can use `\\ `, which you would almost be never needing in regular text.

Comment: (disclaimer: *don't* actually do this) But, if you were really set on using `\newline` an option is to start and end each line with `\hspace*{\fill}`.  In this case, it would be: `\title{\hspace*{\fill}I am an interesting\hspace*{\fill}\newline\hspace*{\fill}headline\hspace*{\fill}\newline\hspace*{\fill}that\hspace*{\fill}\newline\hspace*{\fill}sticks out\hspace*{\fill}}`.